# Shower base and perimeter adhesive & grout

Tags: shower, tile, adhesive, mortar, epoxy

Just put in the shower floor tile with epoxy adhesive & have the perimeter tiles left to do (the very bottom tile against the shower floor tiles)

What Adhesive can I use for this? Is it ok to use thin-set tile mortar or should I use Epoxy?

2nd question ; What kind of grout should I be using for the shower floor?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Thinset tile mortar for those tiles. I would use the epoxy grout for the shower floor and the rest of the tiles. There is a difference between the epoxy adhesive and epoxy grout, make sure you get the epoxy grout.

Comment: Thanks very much! Perfect, just what I needed.